# Appropriate MySQL Table Engine for this Scenario

Tags: mysql

We have a table that will store data every minute per user. We have about 1,000 users. The table only has 11 columns. As mentioned a new record is create for each user each minute, so 1440 records per user per day. The table is highly indexed.

Once created, the data is read and processed via cron jobs every hour.

After 14 days the data is deleted. This is a rolling process.

Generic MySQL wisdom seems to be to use InnoDB for everything, however we have had problems deleting large amounts of data using InnoDB. A memory table is no good as the data must survive a reboot.

Does anyone understand the other MySQL table engines well enough to know is a different type would be better in this scenario?

Here is the table definition:

```
    CREATE TABLE geoc1clo_where.map_data (
      MapID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      Date date DEFAULT NULL,
      DeviceID varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
      Alarm varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      FixTime datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      Valid int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      Lat double DEFAULT NULL,
      Lon double DEFAULT NULL,
      Speed float DEFAULT NULL,
      Course float DEFAULT NULL,
      Address varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (MapID),
      INDEX IDX_map_data (MapID, FixTime, DeviceID),
      INDEX IDX_map_data_FixTime (FixTime),
      INDEX IDX_map_data2 (DeviceID, FixTime),
      INDEX IDX_map_data3 (DeviceID, Date)
    )
    ENGINE = MYISAM
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 98169276
    AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 69
    CHARACTER SET latin1
    COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Comment: Yes currently the engine is MyISAM I have been trying different engines to see if I can solve this through trial and error but would prefer some advice

Comment: "heavy" write and read tables should be InnoDB engine to allow multithreading no question about it  This  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig might be a good read for you... MySQL's framework common_schema allowes throttled deletes  
through the use of QueryScript ( http://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/query_script.html ).. Also adding a index on date column would speed up the query when you delete..

Comment: Ok thanks the colume fixtime is actually the datetime used for deleting. I looked at the delete article, and I fear partitioning may be to advanced for me. Sounds like good old InnoDB is the only answer

Comment: FYI its interesting the table went from 20MB in MyISAM to 75MB in InnoDB

Comment: Yea InnoDB has a different row structure then MyISAM because off transaction support..